# Google Sheets WENN Date and Checkbox

Tags: if-statement, checkbox, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

i'm trying to figure out, how I can get my formula working.
It's telling me I need a valid date.

So if i'm going for this :

J3=checkbox, D5=date formated with =today(), G5=number between 1-30

`=WENN(J3=FALSE;D5+G5)`
This works fine ( today() + 1-30 )

Now here comes the error :

`=WENN(J3=FALSE;D5+G5;);WENN(J3=TRUE;D5+7;)`
This does not work because now it's telling me I need the valid date.

So my question is, how I can get it work?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RMfKFDaCPsn-G23DT6cSnjjImIgB2n1g7z78XE6RsYM/edit?usp=sharing

Days works fine, when I check checkbox it is nothing in there, as I said my formula isn't working ( =WENN(J3=FALSE;D5+G5;);WENN(J3=TRUE;D5+7;) )
This one is working fine as you can see in the sheet ( =WENN(J3=FALSE;D5+G5) )
So when I check the checkbox it should be ( =today() + 7 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=IF(D3=FALSE; A3+C3; A3+7)
```

for arrayformula use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="";;IF(D3:D=FALSE; A3:A+C3:C; A3:A+7))
```

[image]